# Difference in meaning between “elderly” and "old"?

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language

Advice being given because of the COVID-19 pandemic, includes the word “elderly”.

I know someone aged 77 who does not feel elderly but does admit to being old.

Is there more of a negative association to the word  “elderly” than to the word "old"?

Comment: I admin several political groups on Facebook and this issue has come up in the senior citizen group. Instead of “older voters” or “getting the elderly to the polls”, we often use “seasoned” to avoid the negative connotation of “elderly” and “older” and in some cases “seniors”.

Comment: "Old" is how you feel or look (or not). "Elderly" is what gets you on Medicare.

Comment: ...or as Billy Cristal said (1985), ["It's not how you feel, it's how you look, and darling, you look marvelous"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hXydX9p_ZxA)

Comment: This is all very interesting.  Personally I think of "elderly" as a term of respect give its close relation to the term "elders", which to me connotes experience and wisdom.

Comment: @Timbo Likewise if you are elderly then you are an Elder, which means you have a higher level of magical power than ordinary witches...

Comment: @Robusto: _One of_ the things that get you on Medicare (along with being on permanent disability or having end-stage kidney failure).

Comment: @Sean: Pardon my glibness. I didn't mean to make an analogy that is correct to six decimal places.

Comment: @Robusto: It's fine, don't worry.  Just me being pedantic.  :-P

Answer (score 28):

> Is there more of a negative association to the word “elderly” than to the word "old"?

Possibly it is the reverse. I would normally  call myself "old", and  leave the usage of "elderly" to my grandchildren when they are talking about me within earshot. I am pretty sure they use other  and  more colorful language when I am not around.

***Elderly*** is seen as a polite expression, especially when talking about a *group*.

[Cambridge online](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elderly)

Ex.

The elderly are more susceptible to the virus.

...but usually not...

Old people are  more susceptible to the virus.

A famous use of the word can be seen in [LoTR:](https://www.tk421.net/lotr/film/fotr/11.html)

> Frodo: "We're friends of Gandalf the Grey. Can you tell him we've arrived?"
>
> Butterbur: "Gandalf? Gandalf? Oh yes! I remember: ***elderly*** chap, big gray beard, pointy hat… Not seen him for six months."

...and of course Butterbur was being respectful, as any good publican would be.

Comment: Another difference is that, in my experience, "elderly" is usually only used with people, or at least living things, whereas old can apply to anything, living or inanimate.

Comment: @Kevin: That's old news. ^_^

Answer (score 9):

"Old" is an objective description, as a comparison with "young" - though there is no agreement on the age when one ceases be "young" and becomes "old".

"Elderly" is not necessarily either positive or negative, but it usually implies the idea of displaying *signs* of being "old".

For example someone still competing as a power-lifter at age 89, despite several medical procedures including triple heart bypass surgery, could certainly be described as "old" but not as "elderly." (Ref: https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-england-beds-bucks-herts-51825800/bionic-powerlifter-ted-brown-still-competing-at-almost-90).

On the other hand a 50-year-old with poor physical mobility and declining mental capability might well be described "elderly".

For example, see the UK road sign warning of "blind", "disabled", or "elderly" pedestrians crossing the road: https://www.road-signs.uk.com/Road_Signs/Elderly_People/82.html - though some pensioners' organizations have complained that this is pejorative.

Answer (score 7):

The succession of *old* by *elderly*, and now by *senior* or *older*, is just one example of the euphemism treadmill identified by Steven Pinker. Perhaps we are not far from a complete cycle of the treadmill, when (for a while at least) the unpretentious *old* will be back in favour.

Answer (score 3):

"Old" is better used as a comparative than an absolute. If you're 40 in a room full of high school seniors, they're young and you're old. If you're 40 in a room full of people signing up for Medicare for the first time, you're young and they're old.

Elderly is better used as a description of physiological age rather than chronological age. Elderly is used to describe people who have difficulty rising from low chairs, age spots and thin skin on the back of their hands, and other signs of significant physical decline associated with aging. These changes occur at varying chronological ages. Elderly applies when a combination of these signals that the individual has substantially diminished and diminishing physical capacity.

One of the alternatives, "senior citizen", is a chronological description that's about to become obsolete. It was defined by the original Social Security Act to mean 65 or older. Early retirement at 62 and Late at 68 blurred the age. Its about to become muddy. Carter era changes finally phasing in 45 years later push the retirement age up 1 year every 2nd year, stopping at 67/70/73 in 2030. In 2030 "senior citizen" will mean aged over 67, 70, or 73 to the gov't. To the public it may mean over some age between 62 and 73 but its more likely its lost so much of its meaning that a new descriptive euphemism emerges to replace it. "Use it or lose it."

Answer (score 3):

In addition to all of the great answers, "old" is a word which may have a context, while "elderly" is always with respect to biological aging.

Tom Brady is a 42 year old quarterback.  With respect to NFL players, we might say "Tom Brady is old."  We would not say "Tom Brady is elderly."  42 is not a very high age for human beings in general, although it is very high for a contact sports player.

Comment: But we certainly might call him the NFL's elder statesman. Referring to someone as a village elder wouldn't be derogatory. Pointing out that a given individual is the elder sibling would be applicable regardless of physiological age. 'Elderly' does not always have that connotation.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

> At 64, am I really elderly? ... Like most baby boomers, a generation devoted to wellness and working out, I have been operating under the assumption that 60 is the new 40. Suddenly, 60 is apparently the new 80.

(Source: ["Who Are You Calling Elderly?"](https://www.wsj.com/articles/coronavirus-has-boomers-asking-who-are-you-calling-elderly-11584457650), by Kathleen A. Hughes, Wall Street Journal, March 18, 2020, page A11).

The 64-year-old author would like to be identified with one in her 40s. She seems to think of the elderly as being in their 80s.

It seems that there is a negative association with the word *elderly*. Like *middle-aged*, *elderly* is a term that you would apply to others, but less-often to yourself.

> "I'm vaguely hostile to the word elderly," says Thomas Cole, 70, a gerontologist and the author of "Old Man Country: My Search for Meaning Among Elders." "We live in an ageist culture and we have negative associations with words and images of old people."
>
> Mr. Cole notes that the American Geriatrics Society has stopped using the word elderly. "If you submit a manuscript to them and you use elderly, they cross it out and substitute older," he adds.

(Source: [*op. cit.*](https://www.wsj.com/articles/coronavirus-has-boomers-asking-who-are-you-calling-elderly-11584457650))

According to this article, yes, there is more of a negative association to the word “elderly” than to the word "old." Both the author and the American Geriatrics Society prefer "old" or "older" because of the negative associations with "elderly."

Comment: The OP is not asking whether the word *elderly* can carry some negative associations, but whether it carries **more** of them than *old*.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but the OP (=me) writes at the end of his question, "Is there more of a negative association to the word “elderly” than to the word "old"? " .

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Sure, but this answer doesn't provide evidence about the word 'old' only about 'older'. My own feeling is that 'older' is less negative than 'elderly' but 'old' by itself is probably _more_ negative than 'elderly'.

Comment: @Mitch I hope that you would be able to extend the notion of *older* to encompass *old*. If not, perhaps you might see that Mr. Cole, who shuns the word *elderly*, preferred *old* in the title of his book.

Comment: @rajah9 That's not how words work. Words as humans use them are not logical entities (or at least not stipulated mathematical substitutable single meaning entities). Each repeated utterance has its own associations. Surely 'old' and 'older' overlap in many more ways than either do with 'elderly' (for multiple reasons), but their implications and connotations can be very different. 'Old' is abrupt. 'Older' is relative and vague and therefore much less extreme than 'old'.

Comment: Is Thomas Cole trying to be negative towards the "elders" in his book title?  It seems weird to me to title your book "Old Man Country: My Search for Meaning Among Elders" and then say you're hostile towards the word elderly...

Comment: Cole says: "I'm vaguely hostile to the word elderly." In his title, he uses "Old Man" and "Elder," which one can assume he is *not* vaguely hostile toward. Doesn't seem weird to me, but rather consistent with more negative associations with *elderly* and fewer with *old* or *older*.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the other answers have discussed the difference in meaning when the two words are applied to people.  It's also worth noting that *elderly* (almost) always applies to people*, while *old* can apply to pretty much anything that's been around for a while.

For example, we can talk about an *old building* or an *old song* but not an *elderly building* or an *elderly song*.

---

*The only exception I know of is that people will sometimes talk about *elderly pets*.

Comment: They can of course anthropomorphise 'You can also use the adjective for animals or even inanimate objects that are getting old: "That elderly oak tree is going to have to come down." ' [[Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/elderly)] But this isn't really a propos to what OP is asking about, as shown in the body text.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to communication, intent counts for a lot. In clinical communications like that of your example, it is the denotation or definition that matters, not the connotation.

Here are some examples related to COVID-19, where I've highlighted some age-related words:

- We understand your concerns, but if you buy only what you need and stick to the product limits, it helps everyone, especially **the elderly** and people with disability.
  [- Coles Customer Notice](https://www.coles.com.au/customernotice)
- But it's **the old** and the vulnerable – might be people who are immunocompromised, might be people with conditions such as severe asthma or with cystic fibrosis – who are most likely to have a very adverse reaction to this.
  [- Greg Hunt, Minister for Health (Australia)](https://www.health.gov.au/ministers/the-hon-greg-hunt-mp/media/doorstop-interview-about-coronavirus-covid-19-0)
- Current evidence suggests that the most vulnerable people are **those above the age of 70** and who have multiple health problems.
  [- British Association of Paediatric Surgeons](https://www.baps.org.uk/news/announcements/covid-19-information-for-parents/)

Note that the terms "the elderly", "the old" and "those above the age of 70" are all used clinically.

You ask:

> Is there more of a negative association to the word “elderly” than to the word "old"?

There is no sense that any of the terms *in this context* has a more "negative association" than the others.

Answer (score 0):

*Elderly* refers to age related physical/mental condition or capacity, while *old* is quantative.

For example you get "old age pension" at a specific age, regardless of physical health or capacity.  You are "elderly" when you loose some subjective level of capacity you may have had in your youth.

It is not a matter of polite or derogatory synonyms - them have different meanings.

At 70 years, you are objectively and quantatively "old", depending on your state of health, you may not be "elderly".

Answer (score -1):

Elderly - a polite way of saying "of old age"

Comment: According to whom? Please add references to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Elderly sounds to me like a politically correct or at least polite word to refer to the unfortunate but widespread condition of us all aging.  Since aging is unpleasant, people use politeness to be kind or to be hypocritical, or a little bit of both.

Old is just a quantitative, albeit subjective, judgement regarding other people.

Nothing wrong with politeness and, in a civilized society some PC or diplomacy are lubricants of human relationships, but it certainly needs to pass through the BS filter before processing.

Comment: Welcome ondawoad. I disagree with: "unfortunate but widespread condition of us all aging" It is not unfortunate that we are aging. I want to get a lot older! You too, I imagine.

Comment: Well, there is humor in both your comment and my response, of course.  Widespread is an understatement.  We all get old but, purely as a thought experiment, we probably would like to last, more than to get old, particularly with reference to the issues that make old age regrettable, arthritis comes to mind.  As a matter of fact, I guess the use of euphemisms such as 'elderly' comes with the fact that we do not want to throw someone's old age to his/her face too much.

Comment: Opinions do not make good answers. We prefer answers with references from reputable sources.